# spring 3.0.5 library jars

Tags: java, spring

All,
I am starting with Spring and got the Spring 3.0.5 distribution.
I see the following jars:

- org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar

I want to know which jar is meant for which module of Spring (ORM, Core, MVC, AOP etc).
So that I can choose the correct set of jars for my project.

Is there a reference somewhere that explains each jar and it's use correctly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a following chart (from [Diagram of Spring 3.0 module dependencies](http://ogrigas.eu/spring/2009/12/diagram-of-spring-3-0-module-dependencies)):

[image]

As you can see, there are several groups of modules:

- "Core Spring" - `context` and its dependencies (`asm` is missed, `aop` depends on it)
- Web

  - `web` - basic webapp integration
  - `webmvc` (`web.servlet`) - Spring MVC Framework
  - `webmvc-portlet` (`web.portlet`) - Spring MVC for portlets
  - `web.struts` - Struts integration
- Data access

  - `tx` (`transaction`) - basic transaction support
  - `jdbc` - JDBC support
  - `orm` - ORM integration
- Other modules

  - `context-support` - integration with Quartz, Javamail, Ehcache, etc
  - `jms`, `oxm` - JMS and object-XML mapping respectively
  - `test` - for unit testing
  - `aspects` - [AspectJ intergration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) (usually not needed)
  - `instrument`, `instrument.tomcat` - [load-time weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw)

So, if you use build tool that supports transitive dependencies (such as Maven), you usually only need to declare the required modules from **web** and **data** groups, and some from the **other** modules, if needed. Also you may need to declare `context` in order to [configure logging](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/).

For example, if you want to create a web application with Spring MVC and Hibernate, you declare `webmvc` (`web.servlet`) and `orm`. If you don't use Maven, you also need to import their transitive dependencies, as shown on the chart.

**See also:**

- [Diagram of Spring 3.0 module dependencies](http://ogrigas.eu/spring/2009/12/diagram-of-spring-3-0-module-dependencies)
- [Obtaining Spring 3 Artifacts with Maven](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/)
- [Logging Dependencies in Spring](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/)

Comment: Sweet, I hadn't seen that before.  I miss `spring.jar`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Even if you can't use it in your project, you can either create a dummy project with it, or see the spring jar dependencies.

With Maven, you just add the jars you need: `-orm`, `-aop`, `-webmvc` (missing from your list), and maven fetches all the other jars that are required.