# Basic Spring 3 configuration for IOC

Tags: java, spring

Can anybody tell me a basic configuration to use String dependency injection? What are the minimum required jars?
At the moment I'd like to use only Inversion Of Controll, maybe later I'll integrate ORM.
Thanks

Comment: isn't the documentation enough?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677601/spring-3-0-5-library-jars/4678810#4678810

Comment: @Bozho yes there is plenty info http://blog.springsource.com/2010/11/09/green-beans-putting-the-spring-in-your-step-and-application/ on that subject

Answer (score 0):

Try [Spring roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo/start), there is nothing simpler than that to get a full fledged Spring based web application working, with all the dependencies wired together.

Answer (score 0):

Spring STS (an Eclipse distribution customized for Spring available for free from SpringSource) contains several Spring project wizards that produce IoC enabled projects that you could use as examples.

Almost all Spring examples use Maven to define dependencies and download jars automatically from repositories available on the internet.